# Bot was not started message - Facebook Integration

Tags: facebook, bots, dialogflow-es

Ive had working FB integration for a couple of years but recently it stopped working. When I try to setup the integration again I get a dialgflow message

Bot was not started

I have my Page Access token in place but the bot still wont start. Any idea how I would troubleshoot this?

Comment: We need more information. Access token has an expiration date, maybe that is an issue. Have you updated to version 2? are you using fulfillment? have you updated you dependencies?

Comment: Hi, it looks like Im on v1 and my fulfillment url is http not https. Would this stop the bot from starting? It works fine from Try it Now section. Ive updated the access token

Comment: V1 has been shut down on May 31 (as I remember). Most probably this is the reason.